# How combine regex and find in shell script properly

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script which can take numbers from a text document and use these numbers to search for all pictures that include the numbers in their name.

I am working with find and it I got it to kinda work. If the name of the picture is exactly the same as the name in the text document, or if the name of the picture ends with whatever number is written in the text document it works. But if the number is in the middle of the name of the picture, it doesn't find it. So I have been trying to add regex to my find command but I haven't been successful.

```
input="/Users/unix/Desktop/pictures.txt"
input_2="/Users/unix/Desktop/2019/05/23"
while IFS= read -r -u3 line
do
  find "$input_2" -iregex ".*${line}*.jpg"
done 3< "$input"
```

For example if the picture name is Right.jpg and my pictures.txt contains Right, it will find the file. If the picture is called leftRight.jpg, it will also find the File. But if it's something like leftRightleft.jpg, it won't find the picture, so I am a bit confused on how to use regex properly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is simply incorrect. If you break it down, it makes intuitive sense why:

```
.*${line}*.jpg
```

means:

- `.*` -- any character repeated 0 or more times
- `${line}*` -- the contents of `${line}`, with the last character repeated 0 or more times
- `.` -- any single character
- `jpg` -- the literal characters `jpg`

So with your example, if you have `Right` in your file, you'd match actual files like these, which you probably don't want to match:

```
leftRigh.jpg
leftRighXjpg
leftRighttttttttt.jpg
leftRighttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttjpg
```

What you probably want is:

```
.*${line}.*\.jpg
```

Comment: uff thanks, I actually had the meaning of characters wrong. For some reason I though I had it right and never checked it, can't believe I didn't think about that.

Comment: Also note that your file contents could lead to confusion. Suppose you have `one.two` in  your file, that will be interpreted as a regex, and will match `oneXtwo`, as an example.

Comment: Is there a way I can tell the script that everything coming from the file is literal? So that it doesn't convert it to regex like you just correctly noted?

Comment: I'm not sure how extensive Find's regex support is (and it likely depends on which version of find you're using) but you may be able to use `\Q${line}\E` to indicate that everything between `\Q` and `\E` are literal.